# Permission denied error in Google Tagmanager Android

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

In google tag manager, I have created one `container(Android legacy)` to push data to `Google Analytics (Added as tag)`. When I am trying to download current version (published one) it throwing error

```
 )]}',
    {"default":{"errorCode":7,"errorMessage":"Permission Denied.","fieldError":[],
"compilerError":[],"syncError":[],"vendorTemplateError":[]}}
```

Above is the content of json file (which is an invalid json). I checked for the permission and it has `publish` permission which is the highest permission.

Please help

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I have the same issue with IOS

Comment: Yep, forgot to mark this

Comment: @RyanHeitner please check the answer below if it can help your case

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In my case, I was logged in with multiple google accounts and I am very sure that is the what causing this error because I went to incognito window and opened GTM and then everything worked well.

Comment: Great I just logged out of everything and back in !!

Comment: Worked fine. Thank you!!

Comment: It makes me sad that this is still happening... why do we have to log out of all Google accounts OR open a new incognito window to download the container? Regardless, thanks for the workaround :)